# Regular expression to capture multiple lines

Tags: regex

I have some text like this:

*Note: this is example text so the content is unimportant*

```
CAT SAT ON A DOG
REASON:  No reason
CONCERN:  He was cold
BECAUSE:  Cold weather

CAT SAT ON A MOUSE
REASON:  He eats mice
CONCERN:  He was hungry
BECAUSE:  Can opener didn't work

CAT SAT ON A HORSE
REASON:  He wants to ride
CONCERN:  He might fall off
BECAUSE:  Saddle is too big
```

I am trying to write a regular expression that could capture only the 'CAT SAT ON A MOUSE' part, but am having problems capturing the full text.

I have tried:

```
(\bCAT\sSAT\sON\sA\sMOUSE)(.*)\n{2}
```

The idea was to match the beginning part of the string and then to capture everything up till two line breaks.

{2} is to capture the two line breaks.

I have tried many more variations but all I manage to do is to capture the first line only.

Any sort of help would be really appreciated.

Comment: May want to look in to the multi-line flag of regex perhaps?

Comment: What regex, what editor/language?

Comment: How about trying this: http://regexr.com?2u6t0

Comment: It works fine for me in dotall mode - tested at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: @Carl Norum - If the '.' includes newlines, that regex will find everything up until the last `\n\n`. So, really doesen't work.

Comment: @Brad Christie - If all he wants to do is grab a paragraph terminated by a double newline, why would multi-line be the answer?

Comment: @sln: You're right, multiline mode is irrelevant.  There's a rogue meme I've been seeing a lot lately that goes "If the target text is multiline, you have to use multiline mode."  Or maybe "If you want to find a match that spans two or more lines, you have to use multiline mode."

Comment: @Alan More - Yes. To me it depends on the role the line actually plays in the regex. If its solution is clearly multi-line, then I say use it.

Comment: @sln: Judging by the regex, they grab only the next 2 lines and not the "BECAUSE" line. I may be wrong though. (but this was my thinking and why I avoided continuing until a double new line).

Comment: @Brad Christie - I don't know how you extrapolate that from `.*\n{2}` Since the 'lines' aren't captured separtly, there is nothing to be gleaned, and given edge conditions, nothing systematic about it. But, its possible I guess. Not obvious though.

Comment: @sln: Fair enough, and now that I look at it I see they were going for a double new line. This is what I get for tackling things later in the day. :grin:

Comment: Thanks guys. Bit of missing information (apologies). I'm using RegExp in Javascript. Found multiline mode wasn't really necessary. Thanks for the thoroughness though. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

You were asking for anything then two line breaks.
You needed to ask for a line break followed by anything twice.

Try this one:

```
(\bCAT\sSAT\sON\sA\sMOUSE)(\n.*){2}
```

Comment: This regex will match 'CAT SAT ON A MOUSE\nBut\nHere'

Comment: To clarify, this will match the higlighted part of '`CAT SAT ON A MOUSE\nBut\nHere`\nIt\nStops'

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. This works to pick up two lines when I'm really looking to capture everything up until two line-breaks

Answer (score 1):

I think your main problem is that your text uses `\r\n` to separate lines, and you're only looking for `\n`.  Try this:

```
/^(CAT +SAT +ON +A +MOUSE)(?:(?:\r\n|[\r\n])[^\r\n]+)*/m
```

`(?:\r\n|[\r\n])` matches any of the three most common line separators (which I'll call *newlines*): `\r\n`, `\r`, or `\n`.  It matches exactly one newline at a time, no matter which kind it is.  Then `[^\r\n]+` takes over, so there can only be one line separator per line.  Since paragraphs are delimited by *two* newlines, the match ends there.

I took the liberty of anchoring the first line with a start anchor (`^`) in multiline mode (`m`).  It's not absolutely necessary to do that, but helps the regex find a match more quickly, and much importantly, to fail more quickly when no match is possible.

(You haven't said which regex flavor you're working with, so I made a wild guess and used JavaScript syntax.)

Comment: This seems to be a fast way to do it, given `[^\r\n]+` is greedy.

Comment: Tried this RegularExpression Pal (online tool) and this didn't work.. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is this regexpal.com you're talking about?  That site doesn't seem to work for me, in FireFox at least.  But it works fine in Chrome.  Or try a different tester, like [this one](http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/regtest.htm).

Answer (score 0):

What language are you working with? That'll help a bit. In Perl, you can add the `m` specifier to treat the multi-lined string as a single piece of text:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

my $string =<<STRING;
CAT SAT ON A MOUSE
REASON:  He eats mice
CONCERN:  He was hungry
BECAUSE:  Can opener didn't work

This is a test, and not part of the string to match.
STRING

if ($string =~ /(^(CAT[^\n]+).*\n\n/s) {
    say "Match: $1";
}
else {
    say "Didn't match";
}
```

In Perl, adding the `s` on the end treats the enter string as a single line.

Comment: The anchors are 'CAT SAT' and 'work\n\n'. Your regex will grab everything inbetween, including other 'work\n\n' that happen to be there. Very far off from what he is trying to do.

Comment: Okay. I see now. I was confused by what he said "The idea was to match the beginning part of the string and then to __capture everything__ up till two line breaks." I will modify my program.

Comment: David W - Still, I think he meant to stop at the first double newline. So, `/.*\n\n/s` will match everything up to the 'last' double newline, including 2 or more consecutive newlines in between.

Comment: Thanks for this. Am using javascript regexp.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

`(\bCAT[^\S\n]SAT[^\S\n]ON[^\S\n]A[^\S\n]MOUSE\b[\s\S]*?)\n{2}`
or
`(\bCAT[^\S\n]+SAT[^\S\n]+ON[^\S\n]+A[^\S\n]+MOUSE\b[\s\S]*?)\n{2}`

Edit - The regex must be slowed after the first anchor, otherwise the next anchor
could be passed up in favor of speed. This can be done with a non-greedy quantifier
or a look-ahead assertion (which allows aggressive behavior at the cost of a check
that basically nullifies its speed).

Edit2 - Sometimes it may be desireable to match an 'apparent' gap between paragraphs that could include non-newline whitespace.

For example `\n\n` will not match an apparent gap like this:
 'start ... \nend of paragraph\n  \n' when it should.

In that case, replacing `\n{2}` with `\n[^\S\n]*\n` will allow it to match.
Furthermore, since the non-greedy quantifier is used (in this case) `\b[\s\S]*?`,
it is possible to account for and match the paragraph end when it is at or near the end of file. Putting this all together yeilds:

`/(\bCAT\s+SAT\s+ON\s+A\s+MOUSE\b[\s\S]*?)($|\n[^\S\n]*\n)/`

which now looks pretty complicated, but does the complete job.

Comment: I tried this regular expression pal (online regular expression checker) and this didn't work..